# SimpleWebRTC uses its own bandwidth for its service or it is on my host itself?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, bandwidth

My code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html>
     <head>
         <script src="https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v2.js"></script> 
     </head>
     <body>
         <video height="300" id="localVideo"></video>
         <div id="remotesVideos"></div>
     </body> </html>

 <script type="text/javascript">    var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({

      localVideoEl: 'localVideo',

      remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',

      autoRequestMedia: true    });

    // we have to wait until it's ready     webrtc.on('readyToCall',
 function () {

      webrtc.joinRoom('Hello');     }); </script>
```

I want to know if the weight of data (video and audio...) exchanging in the net sits on `simplewebrtc.com` or my own host?

Comment: You are going to need to set up your own signaling server as well. You cannot use the sandbox server in production.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC is used for client-to-client communication. Unless that library you're using does something different (see the docs, ask the authors), it's not using any server resources for the peer communication.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC says:

> WebRTC (where RTC stands for Real-Time Communications) is a technology that enables audio/video streaming and data sharing between browser clients (peers). As a set of standards, WebRTC provides any browser with the ability to share application data and perform teleconferencing peer to peer, without the need to install plug-ins or third-party software.

Comment: oh really? so how these data(video and audio) are exchanging?

Comment: It's a direct peer-to-peer communication, one RTC client to another, the server is there just to connect them and after that no longer cares about what's going on. There's a lot of useful info in the link I gave you.

Comment: and where these videos are stored if we want to record them? in my server yeah?

Comment: You can store them wherever you want (locally or the server) - you just need to record the stream. Maybe that library you're using can do it for you.